# I lost the link to my posts in my menu bar

Tags: posts, menus, pages

I lost the link to my posts. Originally, when I went to "all pages" one would show up as "posts." Therefore it would show up in the menu bar. I think when I set up my site, I wanted to change the posts page to show up as "articles" or "news" instead of "home" in the menu bar. But when I tried to change that I must have screwed something up in the code, or deleted that page or link or something? "Posts" no longer shows up in my list of pages.

My theme is set so that the front page or landing page is the "latest post." So if you go to my site, yes, the latest post is there.  However, if you click on any other page on the site, there is no way - in the menu bar- to get back to the posts. I would like a drop down menu of the posts to be there.  I did put a widget in the side bar that lists the latest posts but I would like it in the menu bar as well. Did I do something wrong?  Can I get it back?

Thank you Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible it's simply been deleted?

Comment: Yes, I could have been deleted.  But I just found out the trash sits for 3 months before permanently disappearing.  Of course it has been longer.  :( Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd check/adjust the Menu (under Appearance, Menu; also usually within Appearance, Customize).

Create a menu if not already there. Then add a "Custom Link" to the menu. The URL is your home page, the Link Text is something like "Home". Drag that menu item to the spot on the menu (the vertical list of all the menu items).

Once you save the Menu, use the "Manage Locations" tab to assign it to the menu area the theme uses.

Add additional menu items as needed.

Comment: I will give this a try.  I have done something similar but may not have taken it to the final - and defining step. Thanks.

Comment: Success!  Great step by step simple instructions, Rick. Thanks!  When at first I could not see what you were saying I should see, I had a hunch and tried opening the site in Safari instead of Chrome which I had been using. 
 Suddenly new editing features appeared!  I had not been able to open all the drop down menus like projects and testimonials - only pages. 
 Now I can open them all.  I could not see "add a custom link" till I opened in Safari.  AND most importantly, I did not see that you could have more than 2 menus!  It was like WP had not updated in Chrome?

Comment: Adding the new menu brought back the HOME page and it picked up all the posts!  Thank you so much, Rick!  Any idea why that happened in Chrome?

Comment: I am almost afraid to ask - Can HOME be renamed POSTS?  or NEWS AND ARTICLES? without losing it again?

Comment: You can call it anything you want. Just put whatever in the "Link Text" field of that menu item. You can change the displayed text for any menu item the same way.  You can also have multiple menus, depending on your theme. The "Manage Locations" tab will show you menu location choices. Changing themes may require re-specifying the menu to use. But if you change back to the original theme, the menu choice you used there should be restored.

Comment: Great.  I am going to try it.  Believe it or not, this happened to TWO of my sites, i am embarrassed to say!  Needless to say, i am nervous.  I will walk the steps carefully.  Thanks so much, Rick!

Comment: I've 'lost' the menu a couple of times when I changed themes. Now I just remember to re-specify the menu to use in the themes. Menus themselves are saved separately; then you select the theme to use in the theme customization (or the 'manage locations' tab). Just remember you might need to re-specify the menu if you are changing themes. (And it is 'nice' around here to 'checkmark' answers that are the solution for you - it helps others see the solution to similar questions.) Glad to help.

Comment: OK, finally getting to this.  So, to be clear, Rick, do you mean that IF in the Navigation Label field, I put, say, "News and Articles" instead of "Home," that I also need to change the URL to "domain/news-and-articles" also?  -- instead of what is says now is just the domain name for URL and HOME for the nav label.  OR, if I change the nav label, that will change it in the menu bar, but it will still pick up the blog posts as if it said HOME?  I don't want to lose it again.  Oh, gee!  And how do I check mark the solution??

Comment: The URL field is where the menu item will take you. The Nav Label is what you will see in the button. As for checkmark the solution, there should be a checkmark icon (dim) next to the answer; click that and it will turn green, indicating that the answer was correct for your question.